# How to get edited value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

im new in MVC 1.

In my project im assigning IList to model and using forloop im assigning to Textbox , dropdox etc... User can change the value as per there requirement.  What i want, how i will get the value present on aspx page in the form of ILIST when user click on SAVE ALL button present at the top of the page.

here are the code which im using for populating form....

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
                       <% using (Html.BeginForm("MyController", "EditCopyRestaurantMealRate", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmEditCopyRestaurantMealRate" }))
{ %>

<%= Html.Submit("Save All Services", ApplicationPermissions.ManageContract, new { name = "submitButton" })%>

<table width="100%" class="edit_restaurant_form">
<col width="19%" />
<col width="30%" />
<col width="19%" />
<col width="*" />
  foreach (var item in Model)
    {       
%>
<tr> 
        <th>
            <label for="DateFrom">
                Effective from:</label>&nbsp;<label class="mandatory">*&nbsp;</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <% string dtFrom = "";

               dtFrom = item.Datefrom.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            %>
            <%= Html.TextBox("DateFrom", dtFrom)%>
        </td>
        <th>
            <label for="DateTo">
                Effective to:</label>&nbsp;<label class="mandatory">*&nbsp;</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <% string dtTo = "";
               dtTo = item.Dateto.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            %>
            <%= Html.TextBox("DateTo", dtTo)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
<%  }      
%>
```

here is the controller code.

```
public ActionResult MyController(string submitButton, IList<CMS.Model.VcmsRestaurant> AddendumMealRates)
{
    // Need to receiv all value in list which is edited

    return View(@"~\index.aspx", AddendumMealRates);
}
```

How I will get the the value in `MyController` which user will edited on the page?

Comment: As i mentioned in my question. How i will get the the value in MyController which user will edited on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You create a method in the controller, that will catch the postback.

If it's simple data you can do something like:

```
public ActionResult EditRestaurant(string dateFrom, string dateTo)
{
    // do something with the values here.
}
```

Or Create a viewmodel, that can encapsulate more complex data:

```
public ActionResult EditRestaurant(EditRestaurantViewModel editRestaurantVM)
{
    // do something with the values here.
}
```

As I can see that you are trying to postback a list of items, in a table, I'll add this to my answer:

As far as I know, you can't easily post that structure of data back, you will either need to use a javascript library like Knockout.js, or use raw javascript/jquery to gather the data, and send it back by AJAX.

Comment: Thanx for the reply but My view model is list and there is multiple value is the viewmodel which will going to edit but user on Page. I had already tried above way but its not help in my case....

Comment: I see your point, I didn't realize that it was a table you were building. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here i found the ans.

```
public ActionResult EditRestaurant(IList<string> dateFrom, IList<string> dateTo)
{
// do something with the values here.
}
```